# Why isn't this sum approaching $e-2$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2n^{k+1}}$$

Easy to see that it [approaches $1/2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E2000%201%2F2000%5E(k%2B1)%20(2000-k)(2000-k%2B1)). But I've cooked this sum hoping it would approach $e-2$. I'll put my thoughts briefly :

1) Imagine I gave you X money at 100% interest rate compounded continuously.
2) Let $n$ be the number of intervals (limit takes to infty)
3) The parent amount $X$ produces an interest of $X/n$ for each of the $n$ intervals yielding a sum of X/n*n = X (not shown in the sum)
4) The $n$ babies of $X$, each $X/n$, produce an interest of $X/n[(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 3+2+1]$
5) The $n-1$ babies of $X/n$, each $X/n^2$, produce an interest of $X/n^2[(n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 3+2+1]$
.
.
.
6) Adding all the baby interests give the sum shown at the top of this post. I feel this should equal $e-2$ because I'm not including the parent $X$ and its simple interest $X$.

I'm pretty sure there is something wrong in my approach, I just couldn't see... Appreciate any help. Thanks :)

Comment: The limit is definitely infinity, note that all terms are positive and the $k=1$ term is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Did you want to divide by $n^3$ or something?

Comment: Ohh yes. Sorry I'll fix it quick...

Comment: @Ian fixed. Thank you :)

Comment: Did you want that $2$ in the denominator? It isn't there in the WA link.

Comment: Yes @Ian was just playing with the "n" in WA. I know that "2" shouldn't affect for how the limit approaches...

Comment: I think the denominator should be $4000$ not $2000$ as in the WA link.

Comment: @rsadhvika it actually does.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan thank you, looks there are few errors. I'll attempt this again and get back :)

Comment: All the best! http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E2000+1%2F4000%5E(k%2B1)+(2000-k)(2000-k%2B1)

Answer (score 0):

with your new sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2n^{k+1}}=\frac{n^{-n} \left(n^{n+1}-3 n^{n+2}+n^{n+3}+3
   n^n-2\right)}{2 (n-1)^3}$$ we get the Limit $$\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you Doc for coming to my post :)  I'm curious why it isn't $e-2$. [Continuous componding gives the multiplier $e$.] I've simply added all the baby interests in my sum. I know that sum equals 1/2, I'm sorta confused why I got the above sum when I was expeciting something like $\sum \dfrac{1}{n!}$

Comment: @rsadhvika you linked the wrong evaluation